# Program only works as expected when unused widget is present

Tags: python, widget

So, I've been writing a python script to give me a couple of statistics about props before I go and buy them at the hobby shop. Yes, its good to experiment, but I'd like to know what I should expect.

The problem I have run into is that the program only outputs the data when the now-extinct wattEntry widget is uncommented. I have gone through and commented everything out that may have been tied to it, but whenever I go and press submit, nothing happens. On the other hand, uncommenting just the widget part fixes the problem. I only want that output in a Label widget, not a Entry.

```
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import  math

master = Tk()
master.title=('Static Thrust Calculator')
Equal = "Notes:"
thrustOutput=StringVar(master, 0)
maxRpmOutput=StringVar(master, 0)
reqWatts=StringVar(master, 0)

Watts="Watts Required:"
Pitch="Pitch(in):"
Diameter="Diameter(in):"
RPM="RPM:"
motorWatts="Max Motor watts:"
Temperature="Air Temperature(f):"
zero=0

#Submit Button Actions#############
def Submit():
    try:
        #wattEntry.delete(0,END)
        #wattEntry.insert(INSERT, zero)
        thrustOutput.set(zero)
        maxRpmOutput.set(zero)
        reqWatts.set(zero)


        pitchValue=np.fromstring(pitchEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        diameterValue=np.fromstring(diameterEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        rpmValue=np.fromstring(rpmEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        #wattValue=np.fromstring(wattEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        #motorValue=np.fromstring(wattEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')

        #Equation for watts required based on pitch, diameter, & RPM ##################################################################
        wattsReq=((diameterValue**4)*(rpmValue**3)*(pitchValue))/(1.888*10**14)
        #Max RPM of a propeller based on watts, diameter, & pitch #####################################################################
        maxRpm=((57367.7)*(motorValue**(1/3)))/((diameterValue**(4/3))*(pitchValue**(1/3)))*3
                #Static thrust generated based on RPM, diameter, & pitch ######################################################################
        staticThrust=((4.39299*(10**-8)*rpmValue)*(diameterValue**3.5)/(pitchValue**1/2)*(4.23333*10**-4)*rpmValue*pitchValue)*101.97
        #Prop RPM based on static thrust, pitch, diameter,
        ###############################################################################################################################
        reqWatts.set(wattsReq)
        thrustOutput.set(staticThrust)
        maxRpmOutput.set(maxRpm)
    except:
        print "error"

Label(master,text='Required Wattage Calculator').pack(pady=10)

#Watt Widgets
######################################################
wattLabel=Label(master, text=Watts)
wattLabel.pack(side=TOP)
wattEntry=Entry(master, text=Watts, width=10)
wattEntry.pack(side=TOP)
######################################################
#motor wattage Widgets
motorLabel=Label(master, text=motorWatts).pack(side=TOP)
motorEntry=Entry(master, text=motorWatts, width=10).pack(side=TOP)
#Diameter Widgets
diameterLabel=Label(master, text=Diameter)
diameterLabel.pack(side=TOP)
diameterEntry=Entry(master, text=Diameter, width=10)
diameterEntry.pack(side=TOP)
#Pitch Widgets
pitchLabel=Label(master, text=Pitch)
pitchLabel.pack(side=TOP)
pitchEntry=Entry(master, text=Pitch, width=10)
pitchEntry.pack(side=TOP)
#RPM Widgets
rpmLabel=Label(master, text=RPM)
rpmLabel.pack(side=TOP)
rpmEntry=Entry(master, text=RPM, width=10)
rpmEntry.pack(side=TOP)
#AirDensity Widgets
tempLabel=Label(master, text=Temperature).pack(side=TOP)
tempEntry=Entry(master, text=Temperature, width=10).pack(side=TOP)


submitButton=Button(master, text="Submit", width=5, command=Submit).pack(side=TOP)

thrustLabel=Label(master, text="Static Thrust(g):").pack(side=TOP)
thrustBox=Label(master, textvariable=thrustOutput).pack(side=TOP)

maxRpmLabel=Label(master, text="MaxRPM").pack(side=TOP)
maxRpmBox=Label(master, textvariable=maxRpmOutput).pack(side=TOP)
wattsLabel=Label(master, text=Watts).pack(side=TOP)
wattsBox=Label(master, textvariable=reqWatts).pack(side=TOP)


mainloop()
```

whenever

```
wattLabel=Label(master, text=Watts)
wattLabel.pack(side=TOP)
wattEntry=Entry(master, text=Watts, width=10)
wattEntry.pack(side=TOP)
```

is removed, it doesn't do anything when submit is pressed. Adding it back in rectifies the problem.
Is there anything you can catch that would cause this behavior?
I don't get any errors in IDLE, and nothing is printed or returned to the console.

these are the only other instances of the widget being used:

```
#Submit Button Actions#############
def Submit():
    try:
        #wattEntry.delete(0,END)
        #wattEntry.insert(INSERT, zero)
        thrustOutput.set(zero)
        maxRpmOutput.set(zero)
        reqWatts.set(zero)
```

--This one does not affect the performance at all

```
        #wattValue=np.fromstring(wattEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        #motorValue=np.fromstring(wattEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
```

--Neither does this one

but uncommenting the widget area does.. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Submit Button Actions#############
def Submit():
    try:
        #wattEntry.delete(0,END)
        #wattEntry.insert(INSERT, zero)
        thrustOutput.set(zero)
        maxRpmOutput.set(zero)
        reqWatts.set(zero)


        pitchValue=np.fromstring(pitchEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        diameterValue=np.fromstring(diameterEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        rpmValue=np.fromstring(rpmEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        #wattValue=np.fromstring(wattEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')
        motorValue=np.fromstring(wattEntry.get(), dtype=float, sep=' ')

        #Equation for watts required based on pitch, diameter, & RPM ##################################################################
        wattsReq=((diameterValue**4)*(rpmValue**3)*(pitchValue))/(1.888*10**14)
        #Max RPM of a propeller based on watts, diameter, & pitch #####################################################################
        maxRpm=((57367.7)*(motorValue**(1/3)))/((diameterValue**(4/3))*(pitchValue**(1/3)))*3
                #Static thrust generated based on RPM, diameter, & pitch ######################################################################
        staticThrust=((4.39299*(10**-8)*rpmValue)*(diameterValue**3.5)/(pitchValue**1/2)*(4.23333*10**-4)*rpmValue*pitchValue)*101.97
        #Prop RPM based on static thrust, pitch, diameter,
        ###############################################################################################################################
        reqWatts.set(wattsReq)
        thrustOutput.set(staticThrust)
        maxRpmOutput.set(maxRpm)
    except:
        print "error"
        raise
```

now you will see why you get the error and immediatly can find the resolution to it ;P

**(alot of those calculations need watts (you will need to change your calculations or set watts to a static value))**

Comment: I looked back into the maxRpm calculation and found that one of the variables was calling on the wattEntry, and not the motor wattage entry. Got that connected to the correct Entry box and it worked flawlessly. Thank you for suggesting to look back at those!